# call action of another controller

Tags: yii

i have a grid view and i would like to get value of column from another action controller.
at now i have this in controller 1

```
   array(
        'name'=>'title',
        'value'=>array($this,'Action2'),
    ),
```

and i get this error:

```
controller1 and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "Action2".
```

if i replace $this with "controller2"

```
   array(
        'name'=>'title',
        'value'=>array('controller2','Action2'),
    ),
```

i get this error

```
call_user_func_array() [<a href='function.call-user-func-array'>function.call-user-func-array</a>]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'controller2::action2' was given
```

maybe this is bad practice but is this feasible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's bad practice to use controller actions this way. Better place your code in model's method. But if you still want to do this, here is one way:

```
'value' => function() {
    list($controller) = Yii::app()->createController('controllerId');
    return $controller->actionTest();
}
```

Here is another:

```
'value' => function() {
    $controller = new TestController('test');
    return $controller->actionTest();
}
```

Comment: i tested it but i get a 500 internal server error.i didn't place it in model beacause it is a html/swf. if i want to publish controller as component -maybe better solution- how do change value in 'value'=>array($this,'Action2'), ?

Comment: What does server error says? Maybe something is wrong in your action? Does your controller located in module? Please provide more information so we can better understand your situation. Also if you need controller action just for rendering piece of html, you can use partials.

Comment: solved.i used component and replace 'value'=>array($this,'Action2'), with 'class'=>'ComponentClassName'

Answer (score 5):

You can use this solution:

```
Yii::app()->runController('category/view/id/1');
```