# Forward data from one controller action to other in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Is it possible to forward data from one controller action to other before the render? Basically, I want to now if we have something that Zend _forward does?

Here is my scenario. I have a payment gateway that returns data back to my controller action, what I want is to handle data on separate controller/action but render the home page (without redirection). Is it possible to forward control from one controller/action to other ?

Can anybody suggest me can I go for ?

Comment: You could simply extract the relevant part of your controller to another method and use it on both. Is this an option?

Comment: @dminones No I want complete render

Comment: did you try this: $this->actionIndex($data); It should work

Comment: @dminones my action is in different controller

Comment: Ok, is more clear now, did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323576/call-action-of-another-controller?

Answer (score 24):

In Yii 2, you can use this which yields the same result of forward():

```
Yii::$app->runAction('new_controller/new_action', ['param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2']);
```

Comment: if you want to render this in a modal, add `$this->layout = false;` to your controller action

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know Yii 1 had forward method in controller that allowed you to forward to different controller/action with simply:

```
$this->forward("new_controller/new_action");
```

I'm sure something similar could be working in Yii2 too.

Comment: He asked for the Yii2 version