# Yii2 How to call controller action from the view

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a function in the controller that manipulates data the way I wanted. Now I want to call that function in the `index.php` file in the `view`. How do I do that?

In my controller

```
function actionTesting($params){
    .....
}
```

How can I call it in the view like..

```
<?php
   echo $this->testing($params);//Calling unknown method: yii\web\View::testing()
?>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not call controller actions from view. I think it violates MVC pattern.

As for the error, it's clear, `$this` in view refers to `yii\web\View`, not to the controller and `testing` method obviously doesn't exist there.

There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251890/forward-data-from-one-controller-action-to-other-in-yii2) asked before, here is possible solution (credits for **Manesh**):

```
Yii::$app->runAction('controller/action', ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2']);
```

This is not enough to just call controller action as usual method call because some events need to be applied, etc.

I don't recommend to use this approach, it's better to move your logic to component / model depending on type of it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this.

```
echo $this->context->testing($params);
```

credits Metacrawler 
original question [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/63169-way-to-call-controller-method-in-view-yii2/)

Comment: This one is shorter, but still is a bad practice.

Comment: And I'm not sure if events will be applied in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
 $parse = array(
   ...............
   'aliasName' => $this,
   ..............
);
return $this->render('viewFile',$parse);
```

and than you can call the function like

```
<?php echo $aliasName->testing($param) ?>
```